# Жидкость в Unity

Tags: c#, unity3d

Как можно сделать подобие воды или лавы в Unity?

Comment: Визуалтно - шейдеры, физика - Nvidia PhysX или любой другой поддерживающий физику жидкости движок.

Comment: не думаю что это учебное задание. Скорее как раз таки слишком неточно заданный вопрос. Слишком общий.

Comment: @Andrew, тут скорее важна часть с "вы пытались решить их самостоятельно перед тем, как задать вопрос". Автор ни гуглил и не пытался сделать что-то сам, вот на это и тревога.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Непонятно что имеется ввиду под "подобие воды". Если же с графической точки зрения, то это нужно сделать полупрозрачный шейдер и сгенерировать неровности (волны) програмно на плейне.

Если имеется ввиду физика - то это нужно использовать физический движок вроде Nvidia PhysX или с ассетов юнити которые это поддерживают ( https://assetstore.unity.com/categories/tools/physics ). Тогда сможеш сэмулировать физику воды. Ищи по словам "water" и "fluid".